# Storyboard.Begin() occasionally blocked or delayed

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7

Our application uses an animation to fade out a message window when it's closed.  To do this, we override OnClosing, and if we haven't completed our animation, we cancel the close and start the animation.  When the animation completes, we close the window.  This seems to be a fairly common pattern based on what I've seen online, since Closing and Closed aren't routable events.

The problem is, we occasionally see a window get "stuck" - the animation doesn't seem to occur, so the "finished" flag never gets set and the window just sits there, canceling any close events.  Sometimes, the animation eventually kicks off and the window closes, but other times it seems like its permanently stuck (though obviously you can't tell for sure...halting problem and all that...).

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why the Storyboard won't get kicked off even after calling Begin()?  Without having been able to dig in really deep into the Storyboard code/data structures, it feels like it's waiting for something to happen before it actually kicks off, that never happens.

Here are some of the possibilities that I've ruled out so far:

- incorrect threading (all windows, animations, storyboard, etc. are created/handled/accessed on the GUI thread)
- GUI thread blocked (clicking the X still fires the Closing event, and the GUI thread responds to events in other windows, system tray, etc.)
- GUI thread busy (we're only doing UI work on the GUI thread, and we generally only have one window open and at most one "close" animation running at a time)

That said, here are some things that might be contributing:

- Windows can close each other (in some cases if one is already open, the new one will close the existing one)
- We also have a "fade in" animation bound to the Loaded event via XAML, but that seems to complete correctly.
- We recently removed our "main" UI window, so the application's main window is now a dummy hidden window.

I suspect that last one most strongly because it was added most recently, and this behavior was never reported/noticed before that change (though I can't say definitively it *never* happened before that change).  But other GUI/window-related events still all work, and the fade-out animation logic works *most* of the time.

Finally, here's the meat of our code for doing the closing animation:

```
public class MyWindow : Window {
    private bool _storyBoardCompleted;
    private Storyboard _closingStoryBoard;

    protected Storyboard GetClosingStoryBoard()
    {
        Grid mainGrid = (Grid)FindName("MainGrid");
        DoubleAnimation closingAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        closingAnimation.From = 1;
        closingAnimation.To = 0;
        closingAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

        Storyboard.SetTarget(closingAnimation, mainGrid);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(closingAnimation, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));

        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.Children.Add(closingAnimation);
        storyboard.Completed += StoryboardCompleted;

        return storyboard;
    }

    private void StoryboardCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _storyBoardCompleted = true;
        Close();
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_closingStoryBoard == null)
        {
            _closingStoryBoard = GetClosingStoryBoard();
            _closingStoryBoard.Begin();
        }

        if (!_storyBoardCompleted)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
The issue seems to pop up whenever we open two of these windows very close together in time, and close the first before showing the second.  Essentially:

```
window1.Show()
window1.Close()
window2.Show()
```

At this point, if we try to close window2, it will cancel the close as in the code above, but the animation won't begin (hence the problem).  If we later on call window2.Close() followed closely by window3.Show() (i.e. show a third window), then window2's animation finishes and the window closes - but then window3 is stuck in the same state.  So the behavior almost seems to get "passed on" from window to window once we are in this state.

EDIT:
I've ruled out another possibility - I was wondering whether the "fade-in" storyboard of the second window was somehow conflicting with the "fade-out" storyboard of the first, and somehow affecting the second window's fade-out.  But the problem occurs even after removing the fade-in storyboard.
Furthermore, the problem goes away entirely if I replace the fade-out storyboard with just a half-second dispatch timer (i.e. just a delayed close, no animation).  Just a sanity check that it definitely has something to do with the animation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could quite pin down specifically why this was happening, but it seemed to be related to the fact that I was showing the second window while the first one was still animating.  I still don't understand why this caused problems, but I was able to work around it by waiting for the first one to close completely before showing the second (basically hooking onto the first window's Closed event).

Would still love to know why this behaves this way, in case the workaround of "wait for the first window to close" ever stops being sufficient...

Comment: I would suspect that it's because WPF is based on DirectX and that each window would require its own DirectX window. I don't believe that DirectX can handle multiple windows well, tho I think DX11 has improvements in that area.

Answer (score 0):

#### Did you ever try adding parameters to the Begin method:

```
_closingStoryBoard.Begin(this);
```

Comment: I haven't tried that yet; from my reading of the docs, it seems like passing "this" basically defaults any un-Targeted animations to target the window.  But I only have one animation, and it has a target.  Worth a shot though, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix the problem, but I do think I've figured out a way to reproduce it.